# How to use web request if Jenkins using SSO plugin?

Tags: c#, jenkins, single-sign-on, jenkins-plugins

I'm using a C# web request that retrieves some data from Jenkins API (e.g. getting slave names using a request based on http://hostname:port/computer/api/xml?xpath=computerSet/)

Till now I used it where I provided *username* and *password* for web requests (assuming that users use Jenkins with built-in users mechanism).

Now I have a Jenkins user who installed OpenID plugin with SSO (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/OpenID+plugin) and I'm wondering if I should send *username* and *password* in web request (does not work), just leave it empty or anyhthing else?

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API token which is in your personal page in Jenkins.

See [Jenkins documentation on the subject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients)

Comment: Thanks. 
Do you think it works if my user uses this Credential Plugin?  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin

Comment: That plugin is for outgoing requests, your question was for incoming requests. Not really sure what your question is.

Comment: This Credential Plugin is the only plugin I found (on user's site) that could be related to SSO login. Do you think there should be another plugin that enables incoming logins?

Comment: I have not seen any, always use the apiToken. It is easier and has reasonable security implications. Passwords are e.g. not involved. Only the Jenkins access is open for persons with access to the script.